# Unable to change label text using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, label

**UPDATE:**
I have double checked again my code. The problem with it is actually the placement of the function (which I didn't post it up here) and I have fixed it!

This is just a short summary of my code. But it just won't run even if I put the js **after** my label.

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  document.getElementById('lblSport').innerHTML = 'Hello'; < /script>
```

```html
<label class="lblSport" id="lblSport">asas</label>
```

Comment: it works in stackoverflow snippet by removing the <script type = "text/javascript" > </script>

Comment: @himawanraharja yes that's the problem btw how can you edit and run the snippet here?

Comment: @Webinan well i "coppy snippet to answer", try to erase that and run it but i'm not posting it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wait for the page to be loaded, remove space on script tags and haven't the same name for the class and id

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('lblSport').innerHTML = 'Hello';
}


<label class="lblSports" id="lblSport">asas</label>
```

Comment: Yes, this is definitely an answer but I just found out that the actual problem with it is actually the placement of my function(which I didnt post it out here) ;)

Answer (score 1):

Delete The space before script tag and the end of the script tag and it will work.

```
<script> .... </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The label is undefined in your case because your code is being called before the actual label exists on the page. Try adding your code inside a "document ready" function for this to work. The document ready function will fire when the document is ready (Once the document loaded all it's elements).

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            document.getElementById('lblSport').innerHTML = 'Hello';
        });
</script>

<label class="lblSport" id="lblSport">asas</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your open and closing script html tags contain unneeded space.
It should look like this:

```
<script></script>
```

As well, according to HTML5:

> The id attribute specifies its element's unique identifier (ID). The
>   value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree
>   and must contain at least one character. The value must not contain
>   any space characters.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute

While you can have the same name for class and ID, best practice would probably be to avoid using same names, mainly for readability.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, check this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/6co9wzmo/1/)

```
window.onload = function(){
   document.getElementById('lblSport').innerHTML = 'Hello';
};
```

just ensure that element is loaded to DOM before your change its innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wk63pov0/

```
<label id="demo" >(innerHTML).</label>
```

Js:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = " changed!";
```

please post your full html.